# Getting TypeError: 'Module' object is not callable on celery task decorator

Tags: django, celery

Trying out celery for django I ran into a problem with @task decorator. This is running on Windows 7.

In my celerytest.tasks module I have the following code

```
from celery import task

@task
def add(x,y):
    return x + y
```

From the command prompt I run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Trying to import my module from shell:

```
from celerytest.tasks import add
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> from celerytest.tasks import add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "d:\...\celerytest\tasks.py", line 8, in <module>
   @task
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried googling this for a long time, but it seems I am the only one in the world with this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I was reading the documentation for 2.6.0 rc3, but installed 2.5.3.

http://ask.github.com/celery/django/first-steps-with-django.html

When using the import like this:

```
from celery.task import task
```

everything seems to work.

Comment: With that import, I'm getting a deprecation warning, however. Better: `from celery.tasks import task`.