# celery task decorator throws "TypeError: 'Module object is not callable"

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying desperately to get Celery to play nicely with Django, but to no avail. I am getting tripped up on the following:

project/settings.py:

```
...

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'django://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django://'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

...
```

*app/tasks.py:*

```
from celery.task import task

@task()
def scheduled_task(param1, param2):
    ...
    return something
```

Calling `scheduled_task(param1, param2)` directly (without the decorator) works as expected. However when adding the decorator and firing up the 'development' celery worker like so:

```
python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

...I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've pinned this down to the `@task` decorator. Every combination I try fails, including:

```
from celery import task
from celery.task import task
from celery.task.base import task

@task
@task()
@task.task
@task.task()
@celery.task
@celery.task()
```

Nothing seems to make any difference to the call stack in the exception, they all *appear* to think that `task` is a module, and not callable! To make things even more frustrating:

```
>>> from celery.task import task
>>> task
<function task at 0x10aa2a758>
```

That sure looks callable to me! Any idea what might be happening? If I've missed anything, I'm happy to post additional logs, files or clarify anything else.

Comment: May sound obvious, but what if you have all files in the same dir? Also, what's in your manage.py file?

Comment: Something this frustrating almost *always* is some stupid obvious thing that's been overlooked, no question is too stupid to ask! The manage.py file looks like this currently: http://pastebin.com/JaaznH2K

Comment: In regards directory structure, do you mean the files in my Django project (they follow the standard project template as of Django 1.5) or the files in the `django-celery` or `celery` libraries/apps?

Comment: Could you add the trace back with the complete call stack to your question?

Comment: @TrojanCentaur in my little experience it worked having celeryconfig.py and tasks.py all together in the same dir and calling it with `celeryd --beat -l INFO --config celeryconfig`.

Comment: I don't know decorators very well but I think the `task` decorator is expecting `schedule_task()` to return a callable.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Call stack here: http://pastebin.com/Qgcr6EDB

Comment: @TrojanCentaur awesome, thanks! From that I take it that the line `return backend(app=self, url=url)` is where the exception happens. So whatever `backend` is, it doesn't seem to be a callable. I would try to set a pdb breakpoint in that file (`celery/app/base.py`) by wrapping that line in `try: ... except: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, and then inspecting `backend`, and moving up the stack (`u` command in pdb) to debug where it all goes wrong.

Comment: @dan-klasson Oh, that could be a thing... however, how is it that the `add()` example provided in http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html works?

Comment: @LukasGraf Giving that a go now. Hopefully this might provide something enlightening!

Comment: @TrojanCentaur the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#basics) also mention this: *"If you’re using Django or are still using the “old” module based celery API, then you can import the task decorator like this:"*

`from celery import task`

`@task`
`def add(x, y):`

Comment: @LukasGraf Yes you are right. Ignore what I said.

Comment: @LukasGraf Certainly all signs seem to point to `from celery import task`, but alas, this doesn't appear to work. Same errors. :(

Comment: @TrojanCentaur could you also add the Celery version you're using? According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864436/getting-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-on-celery-task-decorator) this plays a major role

Comment: @LukasGraf 3.0.21 on both `celery` and `django-celery` (installed via pip onto Mac OSX 10.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Converted to an answer from comments)*

From the [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/Qgcr6EDB) I take it that the line `return backend(app=self, url=url)` is where the exception happens.

So whatever `backend` is, it doesn't seem to be a callable. I would try to set a pdb breakpoint in that file (`celery/app/base.py`) by wrapping that line in

```
try:
    backend(app=self, url=url)
except:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace(),
```

and then inspecting `backend`, and moving up the stack (`u` command in pdb,  `d` to go down again, `w` to display call stack) to debug where it all goes wrong.

The [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#basics) also mention this:

> **How do I import the task decorator?**
>
> The task decorator is available on your Celery instance, if you don’t know what that is then please read First Steps with Celery.
>
> **If you’re using Django or are still using the “old” module based celery API**, then you can import the task decorator like this:

```
from celery import task

@task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

So that should clear up any amiguity about what way to import the task decorator is the right one.

Comment: `pdb` looks very useful, haven't played with that before. However it seems to be crashing, and I can't tell if it's pdb crashing or it's the fault itself, however the result I'm getting after pressing `c` is the following: http://pastebin.com/mnYu9vv0

Comment: Hmm, interesting. To me it currently looks like the strange behavior could be related to the bug you're experiencing: Line 3 `base.py(357)_get_backend()->None` means `_get_backend()` returned `None`, which pretty much explains all the subsequent failures after your pressed `c` to continue: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'store_result'`.

Comment: It's possible though that this is caused by introducing `pdb` in the mix - in some frameworks pdb doesn't work (the same) as in plain Python, and after you inspected (and possibly modified) the runtime environment in pdb, or spent several minutes in that breakpoint waiting, it's not guaranteed that the program flow will continue like it normally would.

Comment: But all that aside, I get the impression your issue has something to do with the configuration of the result backend. I'm assuming you read [Using the Django ORM/Cache as a result backend](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend)? (Note those docs are for the development version of Celery (current master), not the latest release)

Comment: I'm not using the master version, just 3.0.21 (distributed via pip). But I did follow those instructions prior to reaching out to SO, no luck! I wonder wether or not the backend is referring to `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`, and wether or not moving to something like RabbitMQ might help...

Comment: From what I read in the docs, it *should work* with Django as a ResultBackend - but not sure, haven't ever used Django, only Celery. To be honest, I'm in the dark here. If all else fails, I would consider asking in the `#celery` IRC channel on freenode. `ask`, the author of celery, is there most of the time, and he's incredibly helpful.

Comment: I ended up installing RabbitMQ and using that as a backend: it's working perfectly fine now. `pdb` helped a lot here, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: RabbitMQ is exactly what I use in production as well. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is using Celery beat and gets the same error message. In my app I used

```
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A appname --loglevel=INFO --workdir=/tmp -S django --pidfile /tmp/celerybeat.pid
```

and got this error message. Since I copied most of the code for daemonizing Celery beat using supervisord (you need a special config for this), I did not realize that the "-S django" presumes the use of django_celery_beat package, which I had not installed before. I installed it because it anyway has advantages for production use and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old question, but I got into similar trouble and that worked for me:

project/settings.py:

```
...

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'django://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

...
```